# Understanding operator under a subtitution

Tags: calculus

in my notes, I have the following phrase:

With $x = e^t$ and $x \frac{d}{dx} = \frac{d}{dt}$

How, how come we get $x \frac{d}{dx} = \frac{d}{dt} $? I know if I diferentiate with respect to $t$ I obtain

$$ \frac{d}{dt} x = x $$

I do not understand how this operators are defined? maybe I am misunderstading the notation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With

$x = e^t \tag 1$

we have

$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = e^t = x; \tag 2$

thus for any function $f$

$x\dfrac{df}{dx} = \dfrac{dx}{dt} \dfrac{df}{dx} = \dfrac{df}{dt} \tag 3$

by the chain rule.  Thus,

$x\dfrac{d}{dx} = \dfrac{d}{dt}. \tag 4$

Answer (score 3):

$\frac {dy} {dt} =\frac {dy} {dx}\frac {dx} {dt} =\frac {dy} {dx} e^{t}=\frac {dy} {dx} x$.